# How to remove the create prefix text when adding new content?

Tags: nodes, theming

Tried a couple of attempts and no luck with function framework_preprocess

```
function framework_preprocess_ask_a_question(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'ask_a_question') {
      $variables['title'] = 'Ask a new question';
   }
}
```

Content type is called "Ask a Question" want to change the title from "Create Ask a Question" to "Ask a new question" (removing the create text set by default)

Comment: Is this a template or a form? Which module provides this?

Comment: Its in the template as the community informed me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).

You could also use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) or [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) if you preferred or it fit better with your other custom code and requirements.

You would do something like this in a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_form_ask_a_qustion_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Only change the title on the add form, not the edit form.
  if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {
    drupal_set_title('Ask a new question');
  }
}
```

Or if you want to do multiple content types:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Alter all node forms.
 */
function MODULENAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Only change the title on the add form, not the edit form.
  if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {
    $title = '';
    switch ($form_id) {
      case 'ask_a_qustion_node_form':
        $title = 'Ask a new question';
        break;
      case 'other node type_node_form':
        $title = 'Other title';
        break;
    }
    if ($title) {
      drupal_set_title($title);
    }
  }
}
```

There is also the [node add title](https://drupal.org/project/node_add_title) module that allows you to set the title of the add form per content type.
At a quick glance over the code of that module though I see a few issues so I personally wouldn't use it at this stage, although I will open some issues to try to get them fixed.

Comment: I was hoping not to make another custom. But I can make one module with multiple content type each with its own function call right?

Comment: Yeah, or just use hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() instead and you only need the one function. I updated the answer with an example.